# Is Neo4j's Cypher query language open-source?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

what is the status of the Neo4j's language Cypher? I really like it, but I would like to avoid the Neo4j lock-in. Are there some other Cypher interface like there are in Gremlin?

Regards

Answer (score 4):

Cypher is totally OSS, see https://github.com/neo4j/community/tree/master/cypher . Right now there is one implementation, but potentially there can be more. It's just too early in the evolution to make it a standard, we are still heavily experimenting with it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Peter. GPLv3 means we can not use it in a commercial product, right? Is there a compatibility layer to Neo4j like "Blueprints" in the Tinkerpop stack? We would like to use cypher on our c++ based db.

Comment: i think you can use it, but you cannot not modify it unless you make the modified output GPLv3.

Comment: Exactly, you can use it, just not distribute it (Webapp is fine). And, there is commercial licensing that goes around the issue. Contact me.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Pixy](https://github.com/lambdazen/pixy/wiki), a declarative graph query language that works on any Blueprints-compatible graph database. It is built on Gremlin/Pipes from the Tinkerpop software stack.

Pixy enables complex pattern matching and logic programming on graph databases by translating PROLOG-style rules and goals to Gremlin pipelines that represent graph traversal operations. It has [some additional advantages over Cypher](https://github.com/lambdazen/pixy/wiki/Advantages-over-Cypher), other than avoiding vendor lock-in.

Pixy is available under the Apache 2.0 license.

Answer (score 1):

[openCypher](https://opencypher.org/projects/) has been implemented by many databases. According to their site these are some of them:

- Agens Graph: A multi-model database
- Amazon Neptune
- AnzoGraph: A native massively parallel (MPP) graph analytical database
- ArcadeDB
- CAPS: Cypher for Apache Spark
- Cypher for Gremlin
- Katana Graph
- Memgraph: An in-memory, transactional graph database
- Neo4j: A native, transactional property graph database
- RedisGraph: A graph module for Redis
- SAP HANA Graph